# Why is attempting to use pygame.mixer.Channel.play(Sound) raising a SystemError?

Tags: python, pygame, system-error

I've been having difficulty with getting Sound objects to play in my program; I received no error messages of any kind, the audio file itself is not broken, but every time I tried to run my program, no sound came out of my speakers. The first thing I tried was `pygame.mixer.Sound.play()` in order to play the sound, and when I didn't hear the sound, I double-checked to make sure the speakers on my computer were not muted, I turned the volume up higher, and I tried again. I still didn't hear it playing, so I tried creating a Channel object and telling the program to play the sound on that channel using the following code sample:

```
from time import sleep
from pygame import mixer
###
mixer.init() #initialize mixer module
#########
soundObj = mixer.Sound("mySound.wav") #create Sound object from .wav file
soundChn = mixer.Channel(0) #create Channel object to play sounds from
###
soundChn.play(soundObj, 0) #play soundObj on the channel once - ERROR IS HERE
sleep(soundObj.get_length()) #pause program for the duration of soundObj
```

When I ran my program in order to test whether or not this code worked, a traceback to `soundChn.play(soundObj, 0)` appeared, along with the error message `SystemError: Bad call flags in PyCFunction_Call. METH_OLDARGS is no longer supported!`

Can anyone explain to me--in the plainest English possible, please, because I am very confused--what exactly this error message means and what it is that I need to do in order to fix my problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the version of pygame you've installed on your computer is an old version, using deprecated methods.

As it seems to be working on my computer with both Python 2 & 3, I'd suggest to update pygame by running

`pip3 install --user pygame # or pip2 if using python2`

Comment: Okay, thank you! Do I also need to uninstall Pygame 1.9.1 before installing the new version?

Comment: No you do not, pip will automatically do the required job. However, if it still doesn't work for some reason, you may try to uninstall it and remove all its files before reinstalling it.